# What are the other NFT standards other then the ERC-721/1155?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, nft

The title actually explains my question. When I google this question I only see ERC-721 and ERC-1155. Are there any other NFT standards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are by far the most common NFT standards, but there are others. However, they are almost exclusively based on EIP-721 and EIP-1155 (better to have only one standard). Here's a list I found by searching the EIP respository:

https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/65b55a30bbba2640c9a9638d287929de979a4623/EIPS/eip-4907.md
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/9e393a79d9937f579acbdcb234a67869259d5a96/EIPS/eip-4799.md
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/9e393a79d9937f579acbdcb234a67869259d5a96/EIPS/eip-4393.md
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/9e393a79d9937f579acbdcb234a67869259d5a96/EIPS/eip-4885.md
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/9e393a79d9937f579acbdcb234a67869259d5a96/EIPS/eip-2981.md
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/9e393a79d9937f579acbdcb234a67869259d5a96/EIPS/eip-3569.md
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/86a7b57c534c10ebcdab2ef3f62a4befed2ab46d/EIPS/eip-5007.md
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/e349cc23473cc40a95bb5ea240fae8db98019514/EIPS/eip-5008.md
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/9e393a79d9937f579acbdcb234a67869259d5a96/EIPS/eip-4955.md
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/9e393a79d9937f579acbdcb234a67869259d5a96/EIPS/eip-3440.md
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/9e393a79d9937f579acbdcb234a67869259d5a96/EIPS/eip-4944.md
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/9e393a79d9937f579acbdcb234a67869259d5a96/EIPS/eip-2615.md
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/048c5c91ff0e23ea22c2b4207eae6c6273d9183f/EIPS/eip-4519.md
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/9e393a79d9937f579acbdcb234a67869259d5a96/EIPS/eip-4494.md
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/a9d1ef9bd0a959bfd06da60ee4fb63f1bfa727c4/EIPS/eip-4906.md
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/9e393a79d9937f579acbdcb234a67869259d5a96/EIPS/eip-4341.md
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/9e393a79d9937f579acbdcb234a67869259d5a96/EIPS/eip-1948.md
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/9e393a79d9937f579acbdcb234a67869259d5a96/EIPS/eip-4521.md